# Positive lookahead and negative lookeahead together conditionaly

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm inserting tags into a string with curly brackets like this one: `{tag1}`

String in that case after insertions might be: `hello {tag1}, it's {tag2} today.`

I'd like to prevent when tags intersect though, this I don't want: `{tag{tag2}1}`

I'd like to positive lookahead `(?={\w+})` but also negative look ahead `(?!{\w+{)` and `(?!}\w+})`

For example, `textarea` already contains `hello {tag1}.` and if I try to insert `{tag2}` to position 8, it would become `hello {ta{tag2}g1}.` for which I need a Regex that returns false.

Couldn't manage to merge these rules together. Maybe I'm looking at it wrong all.

Comment: Share the code. You might need to insert all the tags in one pass to avoid processing the same string several times. BTW, lookarounds will not be the safest way to solve this (although `(?![^{}]*})` should work in most cases).

Comment: You are right, I may check at the time of insertion, if there is a closing curly bracket left or no open bracket left of insertion point. If condition passes, keep insertion, otherwise exit.

Comment: So, will you please share that code? Just the regex related part?

Comment: I haven't written yet, I was testing regexes I thought would work on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but all failed.

Comment: What is the initial input? What are the pattern requirements?

Comment: it might be an empty string or a string. It's a textarea and I insert tags with `element.selectionStart`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated question and added use case example.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the criterion here? The position in a string? How do you define the match requirements? Find ...... and replace with .... but except those cases when inside `{...}`. Fill in the gaps for us, please.

Comment: I don't want two right curly brackets or two left curly brackets consecutively  in the string. If there is a left curly bracket in the string, then it must be followed by latters/numbers then closed with a right curly bracket.

Comment: Cool, just use [`/{\w+}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/bMYI1F/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to identify if an overlapping has taken place

```
{[^{}]*{.*}[^{}]*}
```

if this string matches then it is invalid
see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWfoRe/4)

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that it checks whole string if rule applies, not groups? That is more convenient for form validation in my use case.

Comment: I've updated question with my use case example. Your regex is correct for partial match, I'd like to check whole string.

Comment: it does check for the whole string, have a look at https://regex101.com/r/Orjsxt/1 you can check if any match occured or not

Comment: Yes, I can use its true condition to check erroneous case. thanks